# Why am I getting an error with gcc but not with g++ in Linux

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

The line of code below is giving an error with the `gcc` compiler even when this file is saved as `check.c`. The error is at the line `void swap_address(int& a, int& b)` as

**error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token**

I have used this command to compile the C file: `gcc -o check check.c`

but the same code is working fine if I use the `g++` compiler using: `g++ -o check check.c`

Please provide me with the reason why it is working for `g++` and not for `gcc`.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap_value(int a, int b)
{
    a=a+b;
    b=a-b;
    a=a-b;
}
void swap_address(int& a, int& b)
{
    a=a+b;
    b=a-b;
    a=a-b;
}
int main()
{
    int i=5,j=3;    
    swap_value(i,j);
    printf("%d%d\n", i, j);
    swap_address(i,j);
    printf("%d%d\n", i, j);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `int &` thing is something from C++ land. C compiler doesn't deal with this syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`swap_address()` has reference parameters the file has a ".c" extension, so `gcc` is assuming it is a C file and producing an error because reference parameters are not part of C.

`g++` is taking the file as being C++, so it is happy with the reference parameters.

Answer (score 1):

References are a C++ feature, they are not supported in C.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ are different programming languages.

You saved your file with `.c` extension, which makes `gcc` executable to treat it as C language file. Meanwhile you attempt use C++ features in your code (e.g references). No wonder it doesn't compile with `gcc`.

`g++` executable unconditionally treats all files as C++ files, regardless of extension, which is why it compiles with `g++`.